# thymeleaf extras security doesn't work with spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, jwt, thymeleaf

SO as a beginner i have tried to make an ecommmerce website using spring boot 2.2.11 , spring security  , thymeleaf and also json web token , My problem is when a user authentificate the template doesn't change even i put isAnonyms and IsAuthentificated tags of thymeleaf in my template.

I have two question here :

1-/ how to tell all controller that the user is already logged ?

2-/ how to pass the jwt token from the backend to frontend so that the user can make specific request ?

Here is  my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The part Of my Index.html that contains the thymeleaf tags:

```
                <div class="forms ml-auto">
                    <a th:href="@{/login}" class="btn" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><span
                            class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></span> Sign In</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/signup}" class="btn" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><span
                            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Sign Up</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/account}" class="btn" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><span
                            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Account</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/cart}" class="btn"> Cart <span> 0 </span> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </a>
                    <a th:href="@{/logout}" class="btn" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><span
                            class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></span> Logout</a>

                </div>
```

My Controller For Login :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userDto",new UserDto());
        return "signin";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("userDto") @Valid UserDto userDto, BindingResult result , RedirectAttributes ra){
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getEmail(),userDto.getPassword()));
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userDto.getEmail());
        if (!userDetails.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(userDto.getEmail()) ){

            result.rejectValue("email",null,"Wrong Email");
        }

        if (!bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(userDto.getPassword(),userDetails.getPassword())){
            result.rejectValue("password","null","Wrong Password");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            ra.addFlashAttribute("userDto",userDto);
            return "signin";
        }
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        System.out.println(jwt);
        return "index";

    }
```

My Spring Security Configuration :

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/signin/", "/signup","/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")

                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/signin").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/home/logout"));


        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


    }
```

Before login :

[img_before_login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak9TE.jpg)

Image After Login :

[redirect to index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL7Ne.jpg)

Login Successfully and switching to other page :

[switch page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EgIk.jpg)

ps: I will be thankful for any solution or any advice .

Comment: Your login is flawed. This should be part of the spring security filter chain **not** a separate controller. You aren't interacting (properly) with Spring Security. So remove it and let Spring Security handle the login (which it already should do through the `formLogin` you configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can get if the user is authenticated by specifying a `Principal` as [method argument](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) in the `@Controller`. If the value is `null`, then the request is not authenticated. Otherwise, request is authenticated.

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
String foo(Principal principal) {
    boolean isAuthenticated = principal != null;
    ...
}
```

Often you would provide a JWT when authentication success is achieved. Here is an [example application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/49757eb6ead86a6a4e5425b1c29c5cfc5d5e5dd4/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login).

The first step is to provide a way to authenticate the user. In this instance, we validate a username/password with basic authentication.

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    RSAPublicKey key;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.ignoringAntMatchers("/token"))
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
            );
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService users() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            User.withUsername("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .authorities("app")
                .build()
        );
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
    }

}
```

Then after basic authentication is succeeds it reaches the controller which produces the successful JWT in the response:

```
@RestController
public class TokenController {

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    RSAPrivateKey key;

    @PostMapping("/token")
    public String token(Authentication authentication) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        long expiry = 36000L;
        // @formatter:off
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        JWTClaimsSet claims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issueTime(new Date(now.toEpochMilli()))
                .expirationTime(new Date(now.plusSeconds(expiry).toEpochMilli()))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
        JWSHeader header = new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.RS256).build();
        SignedJWT jwt = new SignedJWT(header, claims);
        return sign(jwt).serialize();
    }

    SignedJWT sign(SignedJWT jwt) {
        try {
            jwt.sign(new RSASSASigner(this.key));
            return jwt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE: You didn't specifically ask, but the likely reason the Thymeleaf tags don't appear to be working is that you are in a stateless application, so the authentication is lost immediately after log in since the session is not created.

Comment: Thank Rob For your Reply i understand the first part of your reply . for the second part i have a class name jwt which contains the secret key and all other method like extract claim , is token expired , create token . also i have a class jwtFilter wich conatins the override of the method doFilterInternal . so my question is it is  necessary to  create the class RestConfig or just create the Controller for the Token (if yes what should i add in my Spring Security Configuration Class ?)